# How can I go through a column of lists and remove elements at the same index in another list from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where each row of non lists is followed by a row containing lists in the column values.

| Name | Number | Country | Fruit | Fruit Date | Sport | Sport Date | Color | Color Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | 09/01/2022 | Basketball | 09/01/2022 | Blue | 09/01/2022 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022', '09/02/2022'] | ['Basketball', 'Soccer', 'Hockey'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022', '09/03/2022'] | ['Blue', 'Blue', 'Red'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/01/2022', '09/02/2022'] |
| John | 24 | USA | Banana | 09/01/2022 | Basketball | 09/01/2022 | Blue | 09/01/2022 |
| John | 24 | USA | ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022', '09/02/2022'] | ['Basketball', 'Soccer', 'Hockey'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022', '09/03/2022'] | ['Blue', 'Blue', 'Red'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/01/2022', '09/02/2022'] |

I want to delete the duplicate list values in each list: Fruit, Sport, Color and its corresponding Date index value. I also need the rows without lists to be untouched. I just want the rows with lists to be impacted by this change. The first row is just the first occurrence in each list.

Example Output:

| Name | Number | Country | Fruit | Fruit Date | Sport | Sport Date | Color | Color Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | 09/01/2022 | Basketball | 09/01/2022 | Blue | 09/01/2022 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | ['Banana', 'Apple'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022'] | ['Basketball', 'Soccer', 'Hockey'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022', '09/03/2022'] | ['Blue', 'Red'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022'] |
| John | 24 | USA | Banana | 09/01/2022 | Basketball | 09/01/2022 | Blue | 09/01/2022 |
| John | 24 | USA | ['Banana', 'Apple'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022'] | ['Basketball', 'Soccer', 'Hockey'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022', '09/03/2022'] | ['Blue', 'Red'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022'] |

Comment: In my real dataframe, I have many more corresponding columns for each fruit, sport, color columns that I also need corresponding index value to be deleted.

Comment: If you want to add details, please [edit] the question so that the info is all together. Comments are "used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post"; [more info here](/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: What is this data? I don't understand why you need the lists and the first occurrences in the lists. Isn't that duplication?

Comment: Also, please provide the data in a more usable form, e.g. run `df.to_dict('list')`. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 2):

I think that a loop is inevitable here :

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = [
        list(dict.fromkeys(v)) # to preserve the order of the values
        if isinstance(v, list) else v for v in df[col]
    ]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) that has been [*added in 2.1.0*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.1.0.html#new-dataframe-map-method-and-support-for-extensionarrays) (*formerely* [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)):

```
df = df.map(lambda v: list(dict.fromkeys(v)) if isinstance(v, list) else v)
```

*Timings :*

```
# loop : 907 µs ± 31.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
# .map : 630 µs ± 40.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Output :

|  | Name | Number | Country | Fruit | Fruit Date | Sport | Sport Date | Color | Color Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | 09/01/2022 | Basketball | 09/01/2022 | Blue | 09/01/2022 |
| 1 | Jack | 23 | Canada | ['Banana', 'Apple'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022'] | ['Basketball', 'Soccer', 'Hockey'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022', '09/03/2022'] | ['Blue', 'Red'] | ['09/01/2022', '09/02/2022'] |

Comment: Does not work on my larger dataframe. In my larger dataframe I have many more scenarios with different names.

Comment: It means that you failed to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that matches with your actual data. Also, *"Does not work on my larger dataframe"* means nothing. You gotta be more specific !

Comment: I tried adding more data if it helps.

Comment: You don't explain why the answer does not work.

Comment: It just returns 'Name'

Comment: A screenshot.. ?